# Changes in layout Safari-Chrome button row/col

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

```js
// time
let now = new Date();
let days = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saterday",
];
let day = days[now.getDay()];
let months = [
  "January",
  "February",
  "March",
  "April",
  "May",
  "June",
  "Juli",
  "August",
  "September",
  "October",
  "November",
  "December",
];
let month = months[now.getMonth()];
let year = now.getUTCFullYear();
let hrs = now.getUTCHours() + 1;
let min = now.getUTCMinutes();
if (min < 10) {
  min = "0" + min;
}
let time = `${hrs}:${min}`;
let date = now.getDate();
let dayTime = "AM";
if (hrs > 11) {
  dayTime = "PM UTC";
}
let currentDate = document.querySelector("#current-date");
currentDate.innerHTML = `Updated ${date} ${month} ${year} ${time} ${dayTime} `;

//global variables temperature
let city = "San Francisco";
let unit = "metric";
let apiKey = "13a1b6ce652bc0d4bb4d98d6d58fd9c2";

function showTemperature(response) {
  city = response.data.name;
  let country = flag(response.data.sys.country);

  let temp = Math.round(response.data.main.temp);
  let feelTemp = Math.round(response.data.main.feels_like);
  let tempMin = Math.round(response.data.main.temp_min);
  let tempMax = Math.round(response.data.main.temp_max);
  let cloudsDescription = response.data.weather[0].description;
  if (cloudsDescription == "clear sky") {
    cloudsDescription = "clear skies";
  }
  if (cloudsDescription == "few clouds") {
    cloudsDescription = "a few clouds";
  }
  let humidityValue = Math.round(response.data.main.humidity);
  let windValue = Math.round(response.data.wind.speed);
  let cloudValue = response.data.clouds.all;
  let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
  let h2 = document.querySelector("#current-weather-description");
  let currentDegrees = document.querySelector("#current");
  let minMax = document.querySelector("#minMax");
  let humidity = document.querySelector("#humidity");
  humidity.innerHTML = `Precipitation ${humidityValue}%`;
  let wind = document.querySelector("#wind");
  let clouds = document.querySelector("#clouds");
  clouds.innerHTML = `Clouds ${cloudValue}%`;

  //changes in text C /F
  let symbol = "℃";
  let symbolWind = "km/u";
  if (unit == "imperial") {
    symbol = "℉";
    symbolWind = "mph";
  }
  h1.innerHTML = `${city} ${country} feels like ${feelTemp} ${symbol}`;
  h2.innerHTML = `${day} will have ${cloudsDescription} `;
  currentDegrees.innerHTML = `${temp}${symbol}`;
  minMax.innerHTML = `⬇️ ${tempMin}${symbol} - ⬆️ ${tempMax}${symbol}  `;
  wind.innerHTML = `Wind ${windValue} ${symbolWind}`;
  // making a country flag based on deci
  function flag(country) {
    return String.fromCodePoint(
      country[0].codePointAt() + 127397,
      country[1].codePointAt() + 127397
    );
  }
  //weather icons
  let iconId = response.data.weather[0].id;
  let iconCurrentWeather = document.querySelector("#current-image");
  if ((iconId >= 200) & (iconId < 300)) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/wolk-bliksem.png";
  } else if (iconId >= 300 && iconId < 400) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/regen-zon.png";
  } else if (iconId >= 500 && iconId < 500) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/druppel.png";
  } else if (iconId == 800) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/zon.png";
  } else if (iconId == 801 || iconId == 802) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/wolk-zon.png";
  } else if (iconId == 802 || iconId == 803 || iconId == 741) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/wolk-grauw.png";
  } else if (iconId == 804) {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/wolken-regen.png";
  } else {
    iconCurrentWeather.src = "images/Wolken-regen.png";
  }
}

function showForecast(response) {
  //daycard 0:
  let temp0 = document.querySelector("#degrees-forecast-0");
  let tempCard0 = Math.round(response.data.list[0].main.temp);
  let temp1 = document.querySelector("#degrees-forecast-1");
  let tempCard1 = Math.round(response.data.list[1].main.temp);
  let temp2 = document.querySelector("#degrees-forecast-2");
  let tempCard2 = Math.round(response.data.list[2].main.temp);
  let temp3 = document.querySelector("#degrees-forecast-3");
  let tempCard3 = Math.round(response.data.list[3].main.temp);
  let temp4 = document.querySelector("#degrees-forecast-4");
  let tempCard4 = Math.round(response.data.list[4].main.temp);
  let symbol = "℃";
  let symbolWind = "km/u";
  if (unit == "imperial") {
    symbol = "℉";
    symbolWind = "mph";
  }
  temp0.innerHTML = `${tempCard0} ${symbol}`;
  temp1.innerHTML = `${tempCard1} ${symbol}`;
  temp2.innerHTML = `${tempCard2} ${symbol}`;
  temp3.innerHTML = `${tempCard3} ${symbol}`;
  temp4.innerHTML = `${tempCard4} ${symbol}`;

  function forecastCard(number) {
    let timeCard = document.querySelector("#date-day-" + number);
    let timeValue = response.data.list[number].dt_txt;
    timeCard.innerHTML = timeValue.replace(" ", "<br>");
    timeCard.innerHTML = timeValue.substring(10, 16);

    let iconCard = document.querySelector("#weather-icon-forecast-" + number);
    let iconId = response.data.list[number].weather[0].id;
    if ((iconId >= 200) & (iconId < 300)) {
      iconCard.src = "images/wolk-bliksem.png";
    } else if (iconId >= 300 && iconId < 400) {
      iconCard.src = "images/regen-zon.png";
    } else if (iconId >= 500 && iconId < 500) {
      iconCard.src = "images/druppel.png";
    } else if (iconId == 800) {
      iconCard.src = "images/zon.png";
    } else if (iconId == 801 || iconId == 802) {
      iconCard.src = "images/wolk-zon.png";
    } else if (iconId == 802 || iconId == 803 || iconId == 741) {
      iconCard.src = "images/wolk-grauw.png";
    } else if (iconId == 804) {
      iconCard.src = "images/wolken-regen.png";
    } else {
      iconCard.src = "images/wolken-regen.png";
    }
  }

  forecastCard(0);
  forecastCard(1);
  forecastCard(2);
  forecastCard(3);
  forecastCard(4);
}

axios.get(getApiUrl()).then(showTemperature);
axios.get(getApiUrlForecast()).then(showForecast);

//search engine
function enteredCity(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  city = document.querySelector("#entered-city").value;
  let apiUrlValue = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=${unit}&lang=en&appid=${apiKey}`;
  axios.get(apiUrlValue).then(showTemperature);
  axios.get(getApiUrlForecast()).then(showForecast);
}

let button = document.querySelector("#button");
button.addEventListener("click", enteredCity);
let textField = document.querySelector("#entered-city");
textField.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    enteredCity(event);
  }
});

//geolocatie
function showPosition(position) {
  let lat = position.coords.latitude;
  let lon = position.coords.longitude;
  let apiUrlPosition = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?units=${unit}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&lang=en&appid=${apiKey}`;
  axios.get(apiUrlPosition).then(showTemperature);
  let apiUrlForecastPosition = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?units=${unit}&lat=${lat}&lon=${lon}&lang=en&appid=${apiKey}`;
  axios.get(apiUrlForecastPosition).then(showForecast);
}

function getCurrentPosition() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
}

let geoButton = document.querySelector("#geo-location");
geoButton.addEventListener("click", getCurrentPosition);

function CelsiusToFahrenheit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  unit = "imperial";
  axios.get(getApiUrl()).then(showTemperature);
  axios.get(getApiUrlForecast()).then(showForecast);
}

let fahrenheitRef = document.querySelector("#fahrenheit-ref");
fahrenheitRef.addEventListener("click", CelsiusToFahrenheit);

function FahrenheitToCelsius(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  unit = "metric";
  axios.get(getApiUrl()).then(showTemperature);
  axios.get(getApiUrlForecast()).then(showForecast);
}
let celsiusRef = document.querySelector("#celsius-ref");
celsiusRef.addEventListener("click", FahrenheitToCelsius);

function getApiUrl() {
  return `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=${unit}&lang=en&appid=${apiKey}`;
}

function getApiUrlForecast() {
  return `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${city}&units=${unit}&lang=en&appid=${apiKey}`;
}
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
  color: rgba(29, 48, 49, 0.8);
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  background: url("../images/flavio-gasperini-unsplash.jpeg") no-repeat center
    center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  align-content: center;
  padding: 1%;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin-top: 15%;
  
  overflow: auto;
  min-width: 670px;
  max-width: 670px;
  background: hsl(150, 17%, 98%, 0.97);
  border-radius: 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border: -1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #78879c;
}

header,
footer {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #b2cac8;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 3% 10% 1% 10%;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  color: #121d1e;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

/* 3 column structure */
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
.temp {
  font-size: xx-large;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
}
/*celsius fahrenheit buttons*/

.btn-group {
  margin-left: 80%;
  font-family: verdana;
}
.btn-group button {
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  box-shadow: 0 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #106bf3;
  border: -1px solid transparent;
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #0d6efd;
}
.btn-left {
  border-radius: 50px 0 0 50px;
}
.btn-right {
  border-radius: 0 50px 50px 0;
}
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #0a58ca;
  border-color: #0a53be;
  color: white;
  transition: 500ms;
}
.btn-group button:focus {
  background-color: #0a58ca;
  border-color: #0a53be;
  color: white;
  transition: 550ms ease-in;
  user-select: none;
}
.btn-group button:current {
  background-color: #0a58ca;
  user-select: none;
}

footer a:link {
  color: #1067e9;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:visited {
  color: #a4c3f0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer a:hover {
  color: #bed8ff;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
footer a:active {
  background-color: #7a95bd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#entered-city {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

p {
  padding: 0 20%;
  margin: 5%, 10%;
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  size: 10%;
  width: 85px;
}

.prediction-5dys {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 2%;
  margin: 1%;
  min-width: 637px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 1px 0.5rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.daycard {
  display: inline-block;
  align-content: center;
  margin: 1% 2% 1% 2%;
  font-weight: normal;
}
.weekday {
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 13.5px;
}
.weather_img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.coded a {
  color: #b2cac8;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
  integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js" SameSite="None"></script>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6c2e96ffb2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Weather</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header id="current-date">
    </header>
    <h1 class="weatherFeel">
    </h1>
    <h2 id="current-weather-description" >
    </h2>
        <h3>
          <span id="minMax"></span>
          <hr />
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
              <div class="temp" id="current">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3" id="icon-current-weather">
                <img src="#" class=shownWeather id=current-image>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4 weatherInfo">
              <ul>
                <li id="humidity"></li>
                <li id="wind"></li>
                <li id="clouds"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
          </h3>
    <p>
    <form class="input-group ">
      <input 
        type="text" 
        id="entered-city"
        class="form-control shadow" 
        placeholder="enter city" 
        aria-describedby="button-addon2"
        onfocus="this.value=''">
      <submit 
        class="btn btn-group btn-primary shadow" 
        id ="geo-location" 
        type="submit" 
        id="button"
         >  </submit>
      <submit 
        class="btn btn-group btn-primary shadow" 
        type="submit" 
        id="button"
        
      > Find </submit>
    </form>
    </p>
    <span>
      <div class="btn-group" input type="radio">
        <button class= "btn-left" id="celsius-ref">℃</button>
        <button class= "btn-right" id="fahrenheit-ref">℉</button>
      </div>
    </span>
      <div class="prediction-5dys">
        Forecast
        <br>
          <div class="daycard">
              <div class="weekday" id="date-day-0">
              </div>
              <div class="weather_img">
                  <img src="#" id="weather-icon-forecast-0">
                </div>
              <div class="degrees" id="degrees-forecast-0">
              </div> 
          </div>

          <div class="daycard">
              <div class="weekday" id="date-day-1">
              </div>
              <div class="weather_img">
                  <img src="#" id="weather-icon-forecast-1">
              </div>
              <div class="degrees" id="degrees-forecast-1">
              </div>
          </div>

          <div class="daycard">
            <div class="weekday" id="date-day-2">
            </div>
            <div class="weather_img">
                   <img src="#" id="weather-icon-forecast-2">
            </div>
            <div class="degrees" id="degrees-forecast-2">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="daycard">
            <div class="weekday" id="date-day-3">

            </div>
            <div class="weather_img">                                
              <img src="#" id="weather-icon-forecast-3">
            </div>
            <div class="degrees" id="degrees-forecast-3">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="daycard">
            <div class="weekday" id="date-day-4">
            </div>
            <div class="weather_img">
                 <img src="#" id="weather-icon-forecast-4">
            </div>
            <div class="degrees" id="degrees-forecast-4">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
  <footer class="coded">
  <a href="https://github.com/ElisaSky/weather-app-she-codes-plus" target="blank">Open-source</a> coded by <a href="https://github.com/ElisaSky" target="blank"><strong>Elisah Sky</strong></a>
  
  <br/>
  Photo by<a href="https://unsplash.com/@flaviewxvx?utm_source=unsplash&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_content=creditCopyText" target="blank"> Flavio Gasperini</a> on <a href="https://unsplash.com/wallpapers?utm_source=unsplash&amp;utm_medium=referral&amp;utm_content=creditCopyText" target="blank">Unsplash</a>

  </footer>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

working on my first project ever.
Almost there, just this layout keeps on changing between chrome and safari
and can't seem to find a solution as it keeps on flipping around.
Currently its: buttons, col/row/h1 that change the most.
[way it should look (chrome)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQccB.png)
[way it looks in safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kStak.png)

I used bootstrap for the buttons using a input form.

Comment: It is hard to tell without html and css for parts that look different.

Comment: Hey Sergiy, thought I added it, sorry! here is the code 

Comment: (this is my first ever self written code, so it might not be totally awesome ;-) )